# Is there a library for promptForCredentials with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to learn how to delete users from the Firebase Auth provided, but when I click on the delete button on my html it gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: promptForCredentials is not defined`
I can't find any information on if I am suppose to import it anywhere. I'm using plain vanilla javascript.

Here is my code:

my html includes for scripts:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

javascript:

```
const firebaseConfig = {//my app information}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.database();
const fname = document.querySelector('#fname');
        const lname = document.querySelector('#lname');
        const email = document.querySelector('#email');
        const password = document.querySelector('#password');
        const confirm_password = document.querySelector('#confirmpassword');
        const deleteConfirmed = document.querySelector('.deleteConfirmed');
        const passConfirmed = document.querySelector('#deletePass');

        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user) {
                const user = auth.currentUser
                const database_ref = database.ref('users/' + user.uid).on('value', (snapshot) => {
                    fname.value = snapshot.val().first_name;
                    lname.value = snapshot.val().last_name;
                    email.value = snapshot.val().email;
                });

                deleteConfirmed.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const credential = promptForCredentials();
                    user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(() => {
                      // User re-authenticated.
                    }).catch((error) => {
                      // An error ocurred
                      // ...
                    });
                })
                        
            } else {
                location.href = "/login";
            }
            
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you copied code from the Firebase documentation on re-authenticating a user, which shows:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

// TODO(you): prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
const credential = promptForCredentials();

user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(() => {
  // User re-authenticated.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```

That `TODO` there means that **you** have to implement the prompt for the credentials of the user in whatever way works for your app, and then pass them to the `reauthenticateWithCredential` API.